Why latexmk is not able to run -shell-escape with auxdir?
I am exploring all the possibilities of latexmk since it is used as default in Overleaf, and found nice to be able (locally not on Overleaf) to specify the auxdir so my build-files are not polluting appear my folders.
However, I am facing something that I do not understand.
I like to use glossaries package with automake option to always have my nomenclature updated (since the .gls are generated automatically).
This requires --shell-escape at compilation.
Therefore if I add this option in the latexmkrc and run latexmk everything works perfectly.
But if I run latexmk adding the option auxdir then the .gls files are not generated anymore.
Here is a MWE:

the following directory contents:

root
|-main.tex
|-database.bib
|-latexmkrc
|-build/
  |-


main.tex:

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\PathSymbolsEntries}{./database.bib}

\usepackage[record, automake]{glossaries-extra} 
        \newglossary*{acronym}{Abbreviations}
        \newglossary*{symbol}{Nomenclature}
        
        \setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
        
        \GlsXtrLoadResources[
            src={\PathSymbolsEntries},
            entry-type-aliases={main=entry},
            type=acronym,
            match={entrytype=(acronym|abbreviation)},
            category={same as original entry}
        ]

        \GlsXtrLoadResources[
            src={\PathSymbolsEntries},
            entry-type-aliases={main=entry},
            type=symbol,
            match={entrytype=symbol},
            sort={letter-nocase},
        ]
        

\begin{document} 

\section{Introduction}

    Example of an acronym managed by 'glossaries' package: \gls{ascii}.

    Example of an equation (for symbols):
    \begin{equation}
        \gls{func}(\gls{space},\gls{time})=12
    \end{equation}

    \printunsrtglossary[type=acronym]
    \printunsrtglossary[type=symbol]

\end{document}


database.bib:

    @acronym{ascii, short={ASCII}, long={American Standard Code for Information Interchange}}
    
    @symbol{func, %
        name={\ensuremath{ f }}, %
        description={function of space and time}, 
    }

    @symbol{space,
        name={\ensuremath{ x }},
        description={spatial coordinate},
    }
    
    @symbol{time,
        name={\ensuremath{ t }}, 
        description={time}, 
    }


latexmkrc:

$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S';

So if in root directory I run latexmk -pdf the .gls file is generated, but if I run the command latexmk -pdf -auxdir=./build then no ./gls (nor .glg is generated.
However, the file build/main.log says: runsystem(bib2gls main)...executed..
Is it incompatibility between --shell-escape and -auxdir or am I misunderstanding something or another explanation ?

I don't know if glossaries can do this, but you probably need to tell bib2gls that database.bib is in the parent directory, but have the package find it in the working directory during compilation. generally, using a build directory like this is not recommended. it is typically the source of nothing but headaches. so I'd recommend using a flat directory structure, but, if you don't want to do that, I think that's what you'd need to do. the other thing you might be able to do is put the .bib somewhere tex can find it e.g. under your home tex tree. but I have no idea how bib2gls works.

build files are not 'pollution'. by all means say you personally prefer not to see them, but they aren't some contamination and they will not sully the purity of other files :-).

@cfr To be fair it's not an inherit issue with output/aux directory, more of "most package authors don't test with non-default output directory ⟹ most packages doesn't support out of the box". Although it certainly is simplest for "support people" to direct other people to just don't use these…

not really. the whole setup is designed with a flat structure for the working directory. you can easily add inputs from other places by manipulating variables, but generated files are assumed to be in the working directory. sure, package authors can (sometimes) add support for other structures, especially if they are dedicated sub-directories, but, there's no infrastructure for generalised build-somewhere-else. it isn't like make or something. (or l3build.) so it is going against the grain and there's no real way to support that in general from a package.

which is to say, use of an aux or output directory isn't a tex thing. that's not how you do it, tex-wise. moreover, the options depend on the engine and the tex distribution - miktex is different from tex live, for example. and with something like make, there is no problem changing into another directory and then creating a file at the root of the source tree. that's not generally possible for tex. and, of course, make doesn't have to be cross-platform with various restrictions on structure and naming. so blaming package authors is, imho, easy if you don't know what's involved.

Anyway the patch appears to be rather simple because bib2gls already support the --dir= flag… I informed the package author https://github.com/nlct/bib2gls/issues/31 , hopefully it can be fixed soon.

Do yourself a favour and don't use an aux directory. If you must keep your directory clean, either let latexmk clean it for you (will take longer to compile the next time) or use a tools like ltx2any which avoids most of the problems with aux directories.

@all I don't think that the auxdir is the only problem. Because for example, if at parent folder (so parent of root) I use the command latexmk -pdf -cd root/main.tex, I have the same issue. And in that case, the temporary files are 'in-tree'.

@cfr OK if the word "pollution" can lead to debate, however building 'out-of-tree' remains a good practice in every computer science communities (LaTeX included). IMHO it is the same with the fact that having a flat structure, it leads to unreadable, unusable and messy projects. That said, I do understand that it brings extra complications, but I think that it is the role of build-systems (like latexmk or any other) to manage this complexity for you and keep your sources well organized and free from temporary files. An idea could be to do symbolic copy in a build and compile there.

@R.N Compile from the directory which contains your main file.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for the advice and the reference to ltx2any. Unfortunately, according to their git page this tool is not maintained anymore. However, if this tool can do exactly and even more than latexmk I can accept it as an answer.

@R.N Unless you need synctex, you could use the same concept as ltx2any yourself: copy all the files in a tmp folder, run the your favourite build too in this folder, copy the pdf and the .log file back. Avoids all the nasty pitfalls with build directories.

@R.N The fact that building out of tree is considered "bad practice" in LaTeX is most likely a historical accident --- there was no way (before 2024) for packages to get output directory by default, so most packages doesn't support it, which in turns lead to more things doesn't support it, so it tends to break for users… though I've no idea why many users don't acknowledge this.

Under most circumstances, it is preferable not to use the --shell-escape option with latexmk.  Instead one should configure latexmk so that it is latexmk that runs the invoked external programs.  The advantages are: (a) Errors and error messages from the invoked programs are clearly visible to the user, instead of being hidden inside the screen output from *latex. (b) Latexmk can detect dependencies of the invoked programs and use them suitably.
For the OP's situation, which is about the running of bib2gls by the glossaries-extra package, here are two ways to get latexmk itself to automatically run the bib2gls program:

Put set_tex_cmds( '%C %O %S && bib2gls --dir %Y %B' ); in a latexmkrc file. Then whenever any of pdflatex, xelatex etc is run, bib2gls is run afterwards (if there are no errors).  The option --dir is given to bib2gls to tell it about the auxdir.  This solution is simple, but does not detect the dependency on the .bib file, and so a change in the .bib file alone will not trigger a recompilation of the document by latexmk.

Configure latexmk to use the solution already provided in the file bib2gls_latexmkrc in the example_rcfiles/ subdirectory of the latexmk distribution.  I.e., put the code from that file into a latexmrc file. In a TeX Live distribution the directory is at texmf-dist/doc/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/.  This solution does detect dependencies correctly, and deal with errors.  But the current version needs improvement; an improved version will be in the next version of latexmk.


In the OP's situation, where the the document's .tex file and the .bib file are in not in the working directory, but in a subdirectory root, a further item is needed in a latexmkrc file to ensure that bib2gls finds the .bib file:
ensure_path( 'BIBINPUTS', 'root' );

This line is needed independently of whether or not an auxdir is used.
Diagnosis of problems found by the OP
With the setup in the question, there was a serious fatal error raised by bib2gls. But, as the OP found, it was close to invisible to the user.  The only symptoms I found were in the middle of the output of pdflatex to the screen (not in the .log file).  The following lines are from the invocation of bib2gls by glossaries-extra
TEXMFOUT not a directory: build
bib2gls 3.9 (2024-01-30)
File not found: main.aux

The last line indicates a serious fatal error. No error is reported back to pdflatex, and nothing of the output of the invoked program is copied to the .log file.
The first line also indicates what appears to be a bug in bib2gls.  It arises because latexmkrc sets the environment variable TEXMFOUTPUT to the auxdir to inform programs invoked by the \write18 mechanism about it.  Bib2gls does attempt to handle this, but does so incorrectly.
As a general comment about the use of an auxdir and the like, I agree completely with the OP in preferring to have intermediate files segregated into a separate directory instead of polluting the main document directory. I've used such a configuration as my default for many years.  Latexmk is written to support this, with suitable ways to overcome the complications.
